# xamarin android push notification only works once

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

i'm developing an android app and i followed this [link](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/notifications/remote-notifications-with-gcm/) to use google push notification
my problem is that the first time that app starts, push notification work's fine but as I restart my app, push notification stops working and I cant receive notifications.

here is my code:

```
[Service(Exported = false)]
class RegistrationIntentService : IntentService
{
    static object locker = new object();

    public RegistrationIntentService() : base("RegistrationIntentService") { }


    protected override void OnHandleIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        try
        {
            Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "Calling InstanceID.GetToken");
            lock (locker)
            {
                var instanceID = InstanceID.GetInstance(this);
                var token = instanceID.GetToken(
                    "my_id", GoogleCloudMessaging.InstanceIdScope, null);

                Log.Info("RegistrationIntentService", "GCM Registration Token: " + token);
                SendRegistrationToAppServer(token);
                Subscribe(token);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Log.Debug("RegistrationIntentService", "Failed to get a registration token");
            return;
        }
    }


    void SendRegistrationToAppServer(string token)
    {
     // some code
    }

    void Subscribe(string token)
    {
        var pubSub = GcmPubSub.GetInstance(this);
        pubSub.Subscribe(token, "/topics/global", null);
    }
}
```

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" })]
public class MyGcmListenerService : GcmListenerService
{
    public override void OnMessageReceived(string from, Bundle data)
    {
        Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "From:    " + from);
        Log.Debug("MyGcmListenerService", "Message: " + message);
    }
}
```

```
[Service(Exported = false), IntentFilter(new[] { "com.google.android.gms.iid.InstanceID" })]
class MyInstanceIDListenerService : InstanceIDListenerService
{
    public override void OnTokenRefresh()
    {
        var intent = new Intent(this, typeof(RegistrationIntentService));
        StartService(intent);
    }
}
```

and i send notification with this method

```
public static void SendNotification(string MESSAGE, string token)
    {
        var jGcmData = new JObject();
        var jData = new JObject();
        jData.Add("message", MESSAGE);

        jGcmData.Add("to", token);
        jGcmData.Add("data", jData);

        var url = new Uri("https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send");
        try
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation(
                    "Authorization", "key=" + API_KEY);

                System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(client.PostAsync(url,
                    new StringContent(jGcmData.ToString(), Encoding.Default, "application/json"))
                        .ContinueWith(response =>
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(response);
                            Console.WriteLine("Message sent: check the client device notification tray.");
                        }));
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Unable to send GCM message:");
            Console.Error.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
        }

    }
```

do you have any idea?

Comment: Please check the `token` if it have been refreshed ?

Comment: the token is the same when i restart the app

Comment: GCM is old, Did you try the FCM?

Comment: i have the same code on another project and it's working fine.
i don't know the exact difference between fcm and gcm but the mentioned linked in the title leads me to fcm at the end

Comment: - -！ May be your network issue.

Comment: no i don't have network issue.
when i have problem with sending notification to this project, i can send notification to another project

Comment: The tow projects are installed in the same real device?

Comment: yes they are in same device but i'v also removed them one by one and tested them separately but nothing changed

Answer (score 1):

Is this in the emulator?  I had this issue with the emulator and fixed it by turning off the option to preserve application data/cache between deploys.  In Visualstudio it's Tools->Options-Xamarin->Android Options.  Now I get a new token on each deploy and it always works.

Why this happens I haven't figured out.  Maybe it's a security feature that a different build of the app cannot use the same taken?

Comment: no i'm using real phone to test this.
as i terminate app from visual studio the next time i start app, token is not refreshed and it's the same as it was.
maybe i need to create another project in google console

Comment: I'm using Firebase but I think it's the same that onTokenRefresh only gets called on rare occasions when there's a new token.  It will get called on the first load and then maybe not again for months as that token is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

From the official documentation of Xamarin:

"If you force-close the app, FCM will stop delivering notifications. Android prevents background service broadcasts from inadvertently or unnecessarily launching components of stopped applications. (For more information about this behavior, see Launch controls on stopped applications.) **For this reason, it is necessary to manually uninstall the app each time you run it** and stop it from a debug session – this forces FCM to generate a new token so that messages will continue to be received."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/remote-notifications-with-fcm?tabs=windows